# Istio, customized egress with mTLS and existing cert

Tags: istio

I am new to istio and wanting to configure egress gateway to access external service with mTLS enabled. 
First, how can I set secret for cert? I was trying to use bsdssl.com cert but no luck. Anyone have suggestion on how to test mTLS thru egress gateway.
I am also not well verse with certificates.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but if you are asking how to configure an egress gateway to access an mTLS secured external service, you can find an example [here](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#perform-mutual-tls-origination-with-an-egress-gateway).